# Why I get different solution when solving differential equation system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Today I posted this question.

> $$x'=\begin{pmatrix}4 & -5\\-6 & -3\end{pmatrix}x$$ with $x=(x_1(t),x_2(t))^T$.
>
> Beginning values are: $x_1(0)=1,x_2(0)=0$

How do I calculate the general real solution of the differential equation system?

---

I get that eigenvalues are: $7,-6$.
The corresponding eigenvectors are $v_1=(5,−3)^T$ and $v_2=(1,2)^T$.

From the initial condition we get

$$(1,0)^T=c_1v_1+c_2v_2$$

Solving this equation yields $c_1=2/13$ and $c_2=3/13$ such that the final solution is
\begin{align}
x_1&=10/13·e^{7t}+3/13·e^{-6t} \\
x_2&=-6/13·e^{7t}+6/13·e^{-6t}
\end{align}

Later I tried using another vector. I used that $v_1=(1,−3/5)^T$ (which is also correct) and I got totally different equation. Shouldn't I get same solution of system of differential equations? Why this happens?

Comment: Which one should I use than haha @Moo

Comment: So both of those are good?

Comment: The solution for the same initial condition is the same, regardless of which multiple of each eigenvector you  take (the constants of integration calculated will differ to balance things out). I can only think you made a calculation error in one or other solution.

Comment: No I didn't. @Paul

Comment: Slow down doing the calculations. A minus sign or something has gone missing:)

Comment: I get same solutions haha, I have found my mistake. @Paul